# convert array to json from SESSION variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, session, session-variables

I am trying to convert an array where I store some 'products' ($_SESSION['cart']) into a JSON format, but it has been impossible for me

The structure of the $_SESSION['cart'] variable is

```
$_SESSION['cart']['id_product']['quantity']
```

I'm using this code to obtain each product, I think i can obtain an array from here

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id_product => $quantity) { 
code
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just use [the built-in function `json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$myjson = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Substitute whatever variable you want, e.g., `$_SESSION['cart']['id_product']['quantity']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['cart'] = array('test' => 'stuff');
      echo json_encode($_SESSION); //Prints {"cart":{"test":"stuff"}}
   ?>
```